# Is there a name for a trampoline class?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm designing a programming language and one feature I'd like to add is a cross between a [trampoline function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) and a `class`.  That is, a class which takes in a literal akin to a `generic class` taking in a `type`.  I'm stuck on a name for these because I haven't encountered them in a language before, is there something which already means this concept or something close?  Using `trampoline class` is an option, but if there's something that more accurately describes this or is already in use in another language I'd prefer to go with it to cut down on the amount of jargon required in the documentation.

Pseudo-code follows to illustrate this principle in case it is not clear from the above:

```
class Point<const int n> {
    private float[n] _value;
    Point() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            this._value[i] = 0f;
        }
    }
    Point(Point<o> other) {
        for (int i = 0; i < min(n, o); i++) {
            this._value[i] = 0f;
        }
    }
    public static float operator [index] (optional float value = null) {
        if (value != null) { this._value[index] = value; }
        return (this._value[index]);
    }
    public static Point<max(o, p)> operator + (Point<const int o> p1, Point<const int p> p2) {
        Point<min(o, p)> small = (p1.n < p2.n ? p1 : p2);
        Point<min(o, p)> large = (p1.n < p2.n ? p2 : p1);
        Point<max(o, p)> ret = new Point<max(o, p)>(large);
        for (int i = 0; i < min(o, p); i++) { ret[i] += small[i] }
        return (ret);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [*dependent types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). It means that a type cannot only have type parameters (like generics), but a type can also be parameterized with arbitrary values (the dependent type parameters). For example, you can define the signature of a function that takes a number `n` and returns an array of length `n`.

Sadly, dependent type checking in general is undecidable. This is, because you have to calculate the range of possible values of the dependent type parameters *while the type checking itself is executed*. To actually type check the program, you have to check whether two pieces of code produce the same range of possible values. This is known as extensional function equality and this is the part that is known to be undecidable in general.

Now, it might be true that dependent type checking becomes decidable if only compile-time constants are used as dependent type parameters. However, I am not sure about that.

---

In the comments below, we figured out that the part that seems to be the dependent type parameter should actually not be used for the type checking. Instead, it can be seen as an implicit parameter. It is similar to implicit parameter passing in the Scala programming language.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I might have mixed things up by drawing a comparison to `trampoline functions`, which are similar to the concept on an implementation level but not really in theory - that or by using the `max(o, p)` statement in the pseudo-code.  In reality the dynamic bit allowing for `max(o, p)` is distinct from the feature I'm thinking of here.  I'm looking for a way to pass a literal or computed value (a computed value can be viewed as a literal within the this language in this context) as a generic parameter which is not a type but is typed itself (e.g. an int.)  Upvoted for the info.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I basically guessed what you are asking by looking at your code. Maybe you can provide a code example that only contains the concept you are looking for and no other unusual concept? Also, please add a more detailed description of the feature you are looking for, so we don't need to guess that much. Next, please state how the concept is different from dependent types. To me, the description from your comment above sounds exactly like dependent types.

Comment: The question is for the name of a generic class which allows literals in place of types in the generic definition.  A dependent type is a type which depends on another type or has a value which is in some way constrained by it.  The name of the thing described in this case would not necessarily contain any generic types (a literal such as 1, 2, 3, "a", "b", or "c" would effectively be passed at compile type as a local constant within the class.)

Comment: Another way to look at this might be "a class where the first parameter passed to all possible constructors is the value `n`" where `n` is defined with the notation `ClassName<n> foo = new ClassName();` when instancing.  This would be similar to `ClassName foo = new ClassName(n);` with the implication that the portion of code calling `new ClassName();` need not know the value of `n`.

Comment: Okay, the passed literal that seems to be the generic parameter should actually be ignored by the type checker? It is basically a public field? In this case I don't see the point of adding it to the type notation. Especially, you have to repeat the literal multiple times. For example this line `Point<min(o, p)> small = (p1.n < p2.n ? p1 : p2);` contains the information that `small` is the minimum twice. Also in this line, you don't create a new instance of `Point` but you only assign an existing instance. This should not call a constructor, so it does not make sense to use the notation.

Comment: Parts of your description sounds like implicit parameter passing, like it is available in the Scala programming language. It is a concept that I really don't like, but maybe it is the concept that you are looking for.

Comment: Type checking would be dependent on the language (i.e. in the case of a language akin to c++ you might have to define it as `int n` and in something like JavaScript it would just be `n`.)  It would effectively be treated as an argument.  The purpose of the `Point<min(o, p)>...` line was just to make the logic consistent throughout the pseudocode example demonstrating how it might be used internally to the class.  I chose `Point<n>` as an example because you might have `Point<2>` for a 2D point or `Point<3>` for a 3D point and the example would probably make the most sense concisely.

Comment: Looking at Scala tutorials and references it does seem like `implicit` is closer to anything than I've come across so far.  I don't dislike the sound of `implicit class` or `implicit generic class` so I'll probably go with that.  Thank you, if you want to edit your answer to reflect this information or post a second answer (if StackOverflow allows two answers to the same question by the same person) I'll accept it as correct.  Again, thanks for taking the time to dig this information up.

Comment: You are welcome :-) I added the information about Scala's implicit parameter passing to the answer.